How can I avoid apt search results that contain snap packages?
I have removed snapd and friends after reading a bit here, here and here.
Still, when I run apt search with i.e. thunderbird it returns results which are snapd-related:
$: apt search thunderbird
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done

thunderbird/noble 2:1snap1-0ubuntu3 amd64
  Transitional package - thunderbird -> thunderbird snap

And when I install it, it will inform me that this software requires snapd:
$: apt install thunderbird
apt install thunderbird
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 thunderbird : PreDepends: snapd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.



where I really should see the following:
$: apt install thunderbird
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package thunderbird

Is it possible to configure apt in such a way that it will stop looking for snap-packages in the repos? As it stands now, I get confused and irritated that snap results are cluttering up my searches and I am unsure if a package is available or not. I obviously don't want to see snap-only packages since I don't want to use snap.
I'm currently on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.

I didn't see that you referenced this Ubuntu Handbook resource does this address your issue?

"Is it possible to configure apt in such a way that it will stop looking for XYZ?" No. Apt searches its entire database and outputs full results every time. You can, however, grep the output to exclude common terms like "snap transition"

@graham: That resource explains the same, albeit a bit different, what I've already done. My issue is that the apt repository search is cluttered with snap transition packages - I'm basically asking if there is a way to make sure that all snap-related (transitions and otherwise) is left out of searches. Using grep everytime I search will not help if apt install some-package will default to a snap transition package. Blocking all snap related packages like explained in the link is not viable either, unless there is continously updated list available.

You might then find this reference helpful

I don't see how that guide is addressing the issues I have described.

I think that's because Ubuntu do include thunderbird deb package in system repository. Though, it's an empty package redirect to Snap. Try searching something that's available as .deb but not snap. Or, try to remove the 20snapd.conf file under /etc/apt/apt.conf.d.
